# Rota Laravel com erro 404

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

estou trabalhando numa implementação com React e Node (serviços), porém a API é em Laravel. Para trazer uma informação do banco de dados precisei criar uma rota, num grupo pré-configurado.

Porém quando vou testar a rota ele me dá um 404.

Tentei algumas abordagens e tentei procurar documentações e issues similares que pudessem me ajudar, sem sucesso.

Segue o código:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'areas'], function () {
Route::post('/',                'AreasLayersController@index')->middleware('auth_acl:can-web-search-areas');
Route::post('/points',          'AreasLayersController@interestPoints')->middleware('auth_acl:can-web-search-areas');
Route::post('/points/natures',  'AreasLayersController@interestPointsNatures')->middleware('auth_acl:can-web-search-areas');

Route::post('/points-by-customer', 'AreasLayersController@customerInterestPoints')->middleware('auth_acl:can-web-search-areas');
Route::post('/points/natures-by-customer', 'AreasLayersController@customerInterestPointsNatures')->middleware('auth_acl:can-web-search-areas');
Route::post('/public-entity-points', 'AreasLayersController@publicEntityPoints')->middleware('auth_acl:can-web-search-areas');
Route::get('/public-entities', 'AreasLayersController@publicEntityType')->middleware('auth_acl:can-web-search-areas');  

Route::get('/information/types', 'AreasLayersController@areaInformationTypes')->middleware('auth_acl:can-web-search-areas');
```

});

Todas as rotas funcionam corretamente, exceto a rota que criei: 'information/types' com as devidas implementações (controller e service)

PS. Criei uma rota no insomnia que acessa diretamente o microsserviço e tenho a resposta esperada. Falta realmente fazer com que a rota na API funcione.

Se puderem dar uma luz, agradeço. Sigo tentando enquanto isso.

Uma outra observação: estamos usando ngnix. Inclusive já reiniciei o servidor por completo para ver se identificava as mudanças e nada :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema pessoal.

No caso eu precisei chamar o comando php artisan optimize pra zerar o cache de configurações, rotas e arquivos.

Sucesso! :D

Comment: Em desenvolvimento a recomendação é não armazenar as configs em cache, use as configurações do arquivo .env. Só tome cuidado ao enviar para o servidor esse .env, já vi muito sistema na nuvem com o .env escancarado para o mundo